# Why is Linux Firefox so sluggish recently?

Tags: windows, linux, firefox, google-chrome

I switched to Chrome half a year back because Firefox had become sluggish on my Linux box (both Ubuntu and OpenSuse). 6 months later and the problem remains - anyone know what is going on and any tips to improve? I still need to use Firefox occasionally for Firebug.

Comment: do you have try to launch it with a clean profile? (firefox -p)

Comment: Sluggish how? Does it slow down over time? Do websites load slowly? Is the interface unresponsive? There are many different kinds of slowness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, performance is the real deal-killer for Firefox nowadays. Compared to Chrome it's just too damn slow*, so I don't think your experiences are unique or imply that something is wrong with your install.

Perhaps a refresh of the codebase for 4.0 might help, until then I, like you, stick to Chrome for 99% of tasks and switch to Firefox for Firebug.

<sub>*And not just at the Javascript benchmarks the vendors seem so keen on shoving down our throats, and which I'm almost sure us users couldn't notice the difference in. No, I'm talking about startup time, new tab time, extension load time, the fact that Chrome never expects you to wait while it updates or restarts itself etc.  All this downtime together is part of what makes Firefox so 'slow' and unappealing.</sub>

Comment: good to know I'm not the only one, and I hope this gets resolved or Chrome gets better developer tools

Comment: I found a solution - use abrowser

Answer (score 0):

Do you periodically [clean the firefox internal database](http://www.gettingclever.com/2008/06/vacuum-your-firefox-3.html)? How many extension have you loaded in it?
On openSUSE firefox has a long standing issue...see [my blog to encounter it](http://unixbhaskar.blogspot.com/2010/02/cleanup-firefox-clogging-by-pruning-its.html).. I have posted the solution there.

Comment: or you could paste at the very least a direct link, or the actual solution here ;)

Comment: I've allowed myself to add the links to your post, vote you back to zero and also remove the Signature (see the FAQs ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

Remove Flash, remove Firefox, reinstall Firefox without Flash. Try again. Any difference?

Comment: What does `remove Firefox` accomplish?

Comment: In particular, remove the cache and cookies and anything else that piles up in .mozilla/. The less that Firefox has to track the faster it will be. For more info, see the post you edited below.

Comment: My answer addresses the "any tips to improve" portion of the question.